# \polyset and greek letters

Tags: math-mode, errors, greek, polynom

The `polynom` style (version “2006/04/20 0.17 (CH,HA)” from texlive 2012) has to be told about which tokens represent variables. The [manual](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/polynom/polynom.pdf) has an example like this:

```
\polyset{vars=XYZ\xi,  % make X, Y, Z, and \xi into variables
         delims={[}{]}}% nongrowing brackets
```

When I try to typeset this in a minimal document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\polyset{vars=XYZ\xi,delims={[}{]}}
\polylongdiv{\xi^2-1}{\xi-1}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \xi 
l.4 \polyset{vars=XYZ\xi,delims={[}{]}}
```

So there appears to be a problem trating greek letters as variable tokens. Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this, i.e. to actually typeset a ξ or similar greek letter as a variable in a polynom long division?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The manual seems wrong about this: you *must* use simple letters for your polynomials; but you can use a devious hack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begingroup\mathcode`A=\xi
\polyset{vars=A}
\polylongdiv{A^2-1}{A-1}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Just choose an unused letter for your Greek one, *et voilà*.

[image]

---

A bit of explanation is in order. When TeX is in math mode, it looks at letters (more precisely, character tokens of category 11 or 12) as math characters, which have a *mathcode* attached to them. Control sequences *can* denote a mathcode and this is the case for the Greek letters: the definition one finds in `fontmath.ltx`

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{letters}{"18}
```

ultimately boils down to the primitive statement

```
\mathchardef\xi="0118
```

where the first digit `0` tells TeX `\xi` is an ordinary symbol; the second digit is the "math group" (1 corresponds to `letters`); the third and fourth digits tell the slot in the font where the symbol should be taken from.

With

```
\mathcode`A=<number>
```

we assign `A` a mathcode with the same specifications; actually we don't need to know what mathcode is associated to `\xi`, because any control sequence defined with `\mathchardef` can be used as a number when the syntax of TeX requires one. So with

```
\mathcode`A=\xi
```

we're saying that any `A` in a math formula, from that point on, will just behave like `\xi`. Of course this respect grouping, so all of this takes place in a group; I delimited it with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, `{` and `}` would be good too, but the former delimiters pose less problems than the latter in certain situations.

Comment: I would +1 this 10 times! I just spent 1 hour looking for the source of this error. Thanks!